# use ActiveX in java

Tags: java, activex, vlc, jvlc

Hi all
I am trying to develop a program that uses a program called VLC to display media. This program can be installed on windows; also there is a version for using in java called JVLC. I have used executing vlc.exe as a process. also I have tried to use JVLC. I downloaded a dictionary that contains one interface jar files and some dll files. but there was a problem  and there was an Exception:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libvlc

while libvlc.dll was in that dictionary. I loaded this dll file and other dll files manually but still there is exception.

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError..... Can't find dependent libraries

I am trying to use ActiveX to access installed program. I use java with intelliJ IDEA. I don't know how to do this. I have read [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/beans/axbridge/developerguide/index.html#creating) but I can't understand what I have to do.
Is there anyone can guide me ?

thank you;
sajad

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [EZ JCOM](http://www.ezjcom.com/) which will take an ActiveX (aka COM) object and create a Java class for directly using it.

We used this bridge component some years ago (to integrate IE before JExplorer came along and also to talk to some other COM objects). It works and without too much grief.

Of course, the downside is your application is not portable across platforms; but that is your call!

Comment: So thank you. I installed the EZ and did steps to build jar files, dll files and documents. I added jar to my project but when I wanted to run program I understand this is not free and I must pay around $1955 for it! This is not worthwhile to me!

Comment: there is an Exception : ejzcom.JComException : This evaluation DLL has expired! and a message is shown tell me to purchase from website.

Answer (score 0):

VLCj is what you want these days rather than JVLC (it's rather dead and has been for some time.)

See [here](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/wiki/QuickStart) for getting started with it.